# Magento How can i change request parameters on the fly?

Tags: magento

I tried to write an Observer like controller_action_predispatch and like for the default sort in Magento: store.com/category.html?dir=asc&order=name

in the observer i tried to manipulate the parameters but no succes. I tried for examples always for DESC order so i did like this: Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('dir', 'desc');

But after render the pruduct list it dont work... I sense i have no power on request parameters or is there a way to change them before loading a page and using a Magento event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an issue in product sorting then i will suggest to use Observer "catalog_block_product_list_collection" on this event and then observer class you can use

```
 $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC');
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to share, and about manipulating the request parameteres before landing the page, is it possible? Because i could give it good use for other tasks...

Comment: Yes, you can modify the parameters in this observer.